# UI-Grid server side filtering

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am wondering if it is possible to create a custom filter, which will fetch data to the grid, instead of using already build filters. Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this ? http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/308_external_filtering

Comment: Thanks! I couldnt really find it in their documentation :)